# Sharepoint 2010 multi language knowlegde base site

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, multilingual

i'm currently evaluating sharepoint 2010 as company wide knowlege base. one requirement is that the knowlege base must support 3 different languages. the behaviour should be similar to the msdn library. every kb-entry displays it's content in the language of user. if there is no translation available, then the first available language is shown.

is it possible to achieve this with the sharepoint wiki? or if not, are there other templates / add-ons to fullfill the requirement?

Comment: You may have more luck on the SharePoint StackExchange Site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and the appropriate feature is called **[variations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628966.aspx)**.

> The variations feature in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 makes
>   content available to specific audiences on different sites by copying
>   content from a source variation site to each target variation site.
>   When users visit the root site, they are redirected to the appropriate
>   variation site, based on the language setting of their Web browser.

The variations feature is only available in SharePoint Server, not SharePoint Foundation.